# Touchpad has stopped working!

Tags: touchpad

I was in the middle of watching a video and my touchpad suddenly stopped working. I plugged a wireless mouse up and it works fine, and clicking on the touchpad works as well. I just can't move my mouse.

I have a dell inspiron laptop running ubuntu 12.10. I have done an update recently, but I don't know if that would cause the problem since it stopped working in the middle of a session.

I tried some things I found on here to possibly fix the problem, and now the touchpad doesn't show up in my system setting anymore....

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the driver:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics && sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```